# Saber la fuente de trafico donde se ejecuta una URL determinada

Tags: php

Si tengo una determinada URL ejemplo --> http://www.midominio.com

Y esta URL se añade a una web tipo 'rotador' (fuente de trafico), para que rote un numero determinada de veces.

La pregunta es muy concreta....

¿ Cómo puedo saber la fuente de trafico en la que esta rotando mi dominio http://www.midominio.com ?

O dicho de otro modo el sitio web el cual esta rotando ??

Tengo que acudir al array $_SERVER ??

Gracias
saludos

Comment: Alguna variable en PHP ?

Comment: Si lees la documentación de $_SERVER encontrarás dos o tres opciones, no tardarás mas 5 minutos. Deberías también etiquetar la pregunta con PHP.

Comment: SI,  tienes razon pero yo no quiero utlizar  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; que me da el nombre del dominio actual donde se ejecuta el php.

Comment: Lo que quiero seria algo asi... $_SERVER['URL_de_mi_web'], y saber donde se ejecuta --> URL_de_mi_web,

Comment: saber donde se ejecuta? vos queres saber de donde es llamada?

Comment: Si claro, estoy programando un script que tiene que rotar en fuentes de trafico, y el dilema es muy sencillo, quiero saber el dominio donde se ejecuta una URL determinada. Ejemplo: miweb/rotador/?rot=mi_ID

Comment: Prueba con REMOTE_HOST.

Comment: se puede pasar como parametro una URL ??

Comment: He probado $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];, como me dijeron pero no funciona. No me devuelve nada

Comment: Bueno despues de algunas pruebas parece que funciona con:  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es saber la fuente del trafico de tu sitio web, te recomiendo utilizar las UTM que son:

> Los parámetros UTM son cinco variantes de parámetros de URL utilizados para medir la efectividad de las campañas de marketing en las diversas fuentes de tráfico y medios de publicación.([wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A1metros_UTM))

es lo mas efectivo y las puedes crear a tu necesidad son muy útiles.

Te daré un ejemplo:

```
https://www.google.com.ar/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=hotsale
```

en esta url puedes ver las variables que son enviadas

1. `utm_source = google`  //aquí puedes saber el origen desde donde se
   abrió el enlace.
2. `utm_medium = banner`  //medio en el que fue
   publicado el enlace, tambien podria ser email, etc.
3. `utm_campaign = hotsale` //nombre de la campaña, la cual te puede servir para luego
   hacer un informe y comparar campañas y saber cual fue mas efectiva.

Estas UTM las puedes leer con PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  $data=array();
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $data);
  print_r($data);
?>
```

este codigo te guardara las variables de las UTM en un Array de datos para que puedas leerlas y realizar alguna acción sobre ellas.

Por ejemplo puedes almacenarlas en una base de datos y luego realizar un informe donde puedas filtrar datos por origen (utm_source), medio (utm_medium) y por campaña (utm_campaign) y así saber cuales fueron las mas efectivas.

Te dejo un enlace de una pagina donde puedes crear tus UTM fácilmente: [ga-dev-tools.appspot.com](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

y por ultimo te recomiendo leer bien la documentación de php:

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>   Dirección de la pagina (si la hay) que emplea el agente de usuario para la pagina actual. Es definido por el agente de usuario. No todos los agentes de usuarios lo definen y algunos permiten modificar HTTP_REFERER como parte de su funcionalidad. En resumen, es un valor del que no se puede confiar realmente.

Saludos.